# SharePoint 2010 Crawl Rule Regular Expression Exclude Specific String

Tags: 2010, search, crawl-rules, crawl

I'm trying to figure out the correct regular expression for excluding a specific URL string within a SharePoint 2010.

This is the scenario I'm trying to figure out is the following:

I was to crawl all of `http://site` except for links that end in review?=1

An example of such a link is the following:

```
http://site/view/231312/review?=1
```

Anyone have an ideas on how to create this exclusion?

Any help/ideas would be very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried this one for exclusion?

```
http://site/.*.aspx[?]review=1
```

Comment: Awesome! This pointed me in the right direction. I ended up going with http://site.*[?]review=1